# Проблемы с доступом к файлу

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь загрузить сборку, которая находится в папке debug проекта

```
var asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

выдает

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Как можно загрузить сборку именно с этой папки?

Comment: Загружаете вы всё верно, читаете файл в массив байт и уже из него пытаетесь загрузить сборку. А ошибка ваша, с вероятностью в 90% связана с тем, что нет прав доступа в эту папку, где лежит сборка, либо к самой сборке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var path = Path.Combine(relPath, partialName);
 FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(path);
 var account = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
            fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
 FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow));
 var asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

Простите, недоглядел указывал в качестве пути к файлу путь к директории, а для снятия блокировки с файла, подходит этот код